# Traverse and print keys algorithm in Trie Data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on a project that deals with the implementation of Trie data structure. One of the required methods is print all the keys of the Trie in dfs order. Each node will have a boolean variable that denotes whether its a terminal node or not, and its reference is store in an array of size 10 of its parent. Say part of the branch is 3456 (3->4->5->6), and 5 and 6 are terminal nodes and 6 is the last node of the branch --> that is when printing the keys, I only need to print 345 and 3456 for this branch. But the thing is I'm not sure how to do this using recursion... Any ideas?

By the way, these key digits are not required to be stored as variable in each node, simply refer to them by the corresponding index in the array (ex: 3 means a node is stored in children[3])

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private Node Find(Node x, String key, int d)
{ // Return value associated with key in the subtrie rooted at x.
    if (x == null)
        return null;

    if (d == key.Length)
    {
        return x;
    }

    char c = key[d]; // Use dth key char to identify subtrie.

    return Find(x.Children[c], key, d + 1);
}

public IEnumerable<String> GetAllKeys()
{
    Queue<String> q = new Queue<String>();
    Collect(Find(Root, "", 0), "", q);
    return q;
}

private void Collect(Node x, String pre, Queue<String> q)
{
    if (x == null) return;
    if (x.NullNode) q.Enqueue(pre);
    for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        Collect(x.Children[c], pre + ((char)c), q);
}
```

You may have to tweak it a little for your implementation however.

Comment: Thanks! But at this point I didnt get to know queue yet (I will shortly), and I think I'm not allowed to use it either, as the requirement says no java collection class is allowed..

Comment: What can you use? With linked list the implementation is very similar. With arrays, you just need to pass an index alongside with array.

Comment: I believe my instructor implied that we can only use array and string

Comment: One of the issues I ran into is, when i traverse down the trie, and meet a terminal node, what should I do? Its a key to be printed for sure, but what if it has other children that are also terminal nodes? And my understanding is I'm in the middle of the recursion process so how do I print the next key without having to go back to the root and traverse down all the way to this particular node